# How to say "used usage"

Tags: word-usage

I'm building a user system with multiple tiers - a free tier being one of them.

I need to display "used usage" and "available usage" off the free tier.

I have these 2 wordings that I currently use: free tier used usage and free tier available usage.

If it helps, the free tier has a certain amount of free seconds that a user gets.

How do I improve the "free tier used usage" wording? It doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: "Remaining usage" could work, although many places refer to the "usage" as "credits". "Remaining credits / available credits" are easily understood.

Comment: You have a good point sir.

Comment: Use more numbers. *(free tier) usage: 3/10*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using another word such as [quota](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quota) or [allotment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/allotment?s=t) instead of "usage" to indicate a specific reserved amount of something. Usage means the amount actually used, but if there's a limit on the amount of usage, the limit would be a usage quota.

In this context, a quota is a specified amount of something which is permitted to be used. (The word can also mean a required minimum amount, but that's a different usage.)

An allotment is similar, but usually implies that the thing is being actively set aside specifically for the person, whereas a quota is more likely a limit on how big a share someone is entitled to.

Comment: That's a good insight. I'm gonna go with "free tier consumption" and "free tier available quota". What do you think?

Comment: Glad you like the suggestion, but I'd recommend you wait a while before accepting an answer, to give others a chance to make suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, will do. I also like the suggestion I got in the comment above, with replacing usage with credits. It makes it more straight forward as well.

Comment: Quota could very well be ambiguous; a quota could be a minimum or a maximum, while an allocation is generally used as a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just simplify "used usage" to "**used**"?

Comment: Makes sense, but I also wanted to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac - Perhaps its just the math geek in me, but I'd like to think the best way to eliminate redundancy is to remove the unnecessary extras, not trivially rephrase them.